# Progress of a grunt task in a web application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, gruntjs

I built an app with grunt and I’m currently making a web interface (with node and angular) that use this app.
I created an button that execute the grunt task with the childProcess in NodeJS :

```
child_process.exec(my-command-grunt[, options], callback)
```

It works correctly, but the task takes quite a long time (~10sec). For that reason I show a loader at that time, but I would rather have a progress bar. If there is a way to know about the progress of the grunt task when it is running that will help me to replace my loader by a dynamic progress bar on my web page.

Thank you very much !

Comment: how is your grunt process logging its status?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question very well, but I got the logs on my console (in which I started my node server), the same as when I execute the grunt command in my console (expect that it is not progressive, I got the log in one time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, it is not possible to receive just percentage progress of currently running tasks.

**But there is a solution!**
A `child_process.exec` will return [ChildProcess](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_class_childprocess) instance. You can then access stdout and stderr streams (through child.stdout and child.stderr). These streams are event emitters and you can listen on `data` event and use some regular expressions for parsing this output. Regular expression can be something like `/Running "([^"]*)"/` and then you can match its results and report a progress of grunt to a client.

Comment: Thank you for that ! Do you know if I can do something else than regular expression, like emitting events with grunt at the end of each task ?

Comment: You can use regular expressions to match results from grunt and emit event on each match. But this is just an idea.

Comment: how about creating a npm module for this!

Comment: yep, go for it ;)